# installing MSMQ with bat file or some automated stuff

Tags: automation, installation, batch-file, msmq

We are creating a service which requires MSMQ, and it might happen the boxes where we install doesn't have MSMQ installed. So I want some mechanism which can install MSMQ as a prerequisite when installing my service.

Any suggestions??

Some how i manage to find from the below answer

I am using the below in the .ini file & bat file but its prompts me for windows xp cd(I386) path. Is there anyway to suppress that or give the in the bat file

bat file

```
sysocmgr.exe /i:sysoc.inf /n /f /u:"MSMQsetup.ini"
```

MSMQsetup.ini file

```
[Components] 
msmq_Core = ON 
msmq_LocalStorage = ON 
msmq_HTTPSupport = ON 
msmq_TriggersService = ON 
msmq_ADIntegrated = ON 
msmq_MQDSService = OFF 
msmq_RoutingSupport = OFF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Automate your MSMQ Installation](http://blogs.msdn.com/motleyqueue/archive/2007/10/20/automate-your-msmq-installation.aspx) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Change in registry key at `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup`

- `ServicePackSourcePath` - specify path of I386 folder
- `SourcePath` - specify path of I386 folder

  write the following command:

  sysocmgr.exe /i:sysoc.inf /u:ini path